# How to create ordinal numbers for list item?

Tags: php, numbers, ordinal

I have a list item with this code:

```
foreach ($medias as $i => $media) {

$html .= "<li class=''>...</li>";

}
```

I want output as below:

```
<li class="id-1">...</li>
<li class="id-2">...</li>
<li class="id-3">...</li>
<li class="id-4">...</li>
....
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: Could you add a little more description about the problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($media); $i++) {

  $html .= '<li class="id-'.($i+1).'">...</li>';

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($medias as $i => $media) {
    $html .= "<li class='".($i + 1)."'>...</li>";
}
```

Comment: So you're just assuming that the key is an integer?

Comment: Thank you, it's work. But i have another problem. On my site, 1 page have 10 item and when page 2 load, id repeated 1-10. I want it's continue 11-19

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$x=0;
foreach ($medias as $i => $media) {
$x++;

echo "<li class='id-".$x."'>...</li>";

}
```